# c++: what's the design philosophy of allowing temporary object to call non-const member function?

Tags: c++, constants, temporary, member-functions

I search the stack overflow and people say it's stupid to modify temporary object, so binding temporary object to non-const lvalue reference is not allowed, like you can't pass a temporary object to a function with non-const lvalue reference.

Then why is temporary objects allowed to call non-const member function which has the potential to modify the object and do "stupid" things? You may say, "ha, that's allowed because we want to provide the programmer with some flexibility to do "stupid" things that are in fact not that stupid", which is the reason I can hardly buy because if I buy this excuse, I think that "binding temporary to non-const lvalue reference" can be justified using the same reason.

Thanks! I hardly find any relevant question here. They just told me it's an exception, but why we allow that exception?

Comment: Hope those who down vote my question give me a brief reason for it. Really appreciate your kindly guidance and help.

Comment: Instead of describing a possible situation, better *show* us some actual code. That might be one reason. [Here's a list of other possible reasons](http://idownvotedbecau.se/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: show some code? For a philosophical question? This is an absolutely valid question, and if there is no clear answer for this, it could mean this design decision cannot be justified strongly.

Comment: @HanXIAO: I'd say this: if a function has a non-const reference parameter, it is usually because it is an output parameter. So it is meaningless to use a temporary for this parameter, as the output will be lost. So in a lot of cases, it would be an error to use a temporary for a non-const reference parameter.

Comment: @geza some code would help illustrate what the question is asking. It seems to me that the asker has a clear example in mind, but I for one do not see it. Including an example in code would help make sure everyone is on the same page regarding what is being asked.

Comment: Hmm... I've had a stray thought: this question might be asking the wrong thing. Instead of asking why non-const functions can be called, maybe the question should be about why binding to a non-const reference is not allowed. Surely there is a better reason than "it's stupid". Once a proper understanding of the first case is obtained, the secondary question about functions might resolve itself.

Comment: @JaMiT: yes, maybe. But to be honest, this question is crystal clear without any examples. Loosely phrased, but anyone who has a moderate C++ background, should understand what it is about.

Comment: @geza Thanks! The "output" really helps a lot.

Comment: @geza I suppose my years of tinkering with C++ do not count as a moderate C++ background then. I did not get what this description was talking about until I saw the example in the current answer.
(It's possible that I would have gotten it if I looked at a different time, just because thoughts vary throughout the day. Still, why this objection to making the question clearer?)

Comment: I suppose I still don't get this site. Questions are answered in comments. Reasonable suggestions for making questions clearer are themselves questioned. Guess it's time for another break for me.

Comment: @JaMiT I think maybe I should search and ask the opposite. I think geza helped me with understanding why passing temporary object to function with non-const reference is prohibited. But why binding temporary to local non-const lvalue reference is prohibited and does not prolong the temporary object lifetime is waiting to be answered.

Comment: @JaMiT: because it is not a full answer :) I answer questions when I can do it properly, and I have the time for it. I don't object to make the question clearer at all. And I didn't want to "degrade" you, sorry if my comment was hurtful.

Comment: @HanXIAO: I think the answer is that question is "to be consistent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I am putting some additional materials here. The following materials are quoted from **David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M. Josuttis, Douglas Gregor-C++ Templates_ The Complete Guide-Addison-Wesley (2017)**, **C.2.1 The Implied Argument For Member Functions.**

> “An old special-case permits an rvalue to be bound to an lvalue
>   reference to non-const type when that reference is the traditional
>   implicit *this parameter”

```
struct S{
    void f1() {}//the old rule
    void f2() && {}
    void f3() & {}
};
int main()
{
    S().f1();//Here, I THINK const this is bound to non-const, thus allowing calling non-const member functions.(the comment here is not quoted from the book.)
    S().f2();
    S().f3();//not okay
    return 1;
}
```

Use `-std=c++11` compilation option.
So, this means C++ designers have realized that the old rule of allowing temporary objects, which have implicit `const this*`, to call non-const member function is not so good. So in C++11 they introduced `&` and `&&` suffixing function declaration.

But when it comes to the design philosophy of the old rule of allowing temporary objects calling non-const member function, I think it's not worth diving into this. C++ 11 has make an effort to "emend" this.(Or let programmer control this.)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference, but the rationale here is **not** to avoid accidental modification of a temporary. The rationale is that you don't want to silently **miss** modifying something you **wanted** to modify.

Imagine it's allowed, then:

```
void foo(double& x);
int y;
foo(y); //user wants to modify y, but instead a temporary is modified
```

In and of itself, modifying a temporary object is perfectly OK and often useful. There's no reason to disallow it.

Comment: Thanks! This reason open up my horizon. The devil here is the built-in implicit conversions. As for user-defined types, we can use `explicit` to avoid that if temporary to non-const reference is allowed.

Comment: What about things like `std::string s; s + s = s;`? This is also a silent miss of modification, and it is allowed

Comment: @RomanGolyshev I don't understand the example. What exactly did the user want to modify here?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. my concern here is more about this: we cannot bind temporary object to non-const reference, but in the same time we can modify temporary object using its non-const methods. In my example, we accidentally assign something into temporary object (`s + s = s`). It looks like we are actually able to bind temporary object to non-const reference, but only if this object is bound through `this` (with help of a non-const method). In this case I can also say that I do not want to modify the object that will be destroyed as soon as the expression is executed, but the language allows that

Comment: @RomanGolyshev "we can modify temporary object using its non-const methods". Yes we can, this is by design. "we accidentally assign something into temporary object". It is not accidentally, the temporary object is before your very eyes. What else "s+s" could possibly be? In foo(y) the temporary object is not apparent, and this is the essential difference

Comment: @RomanGolyshev You are right. Only through *this. This is the old special case.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have a factory method, that returns, as recommended, a `unique_ptr`

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> createObject();
```

However you need a shared pointer to created object. So you write

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> mySharedObject{createObject().release()};
```

And you have just called a non-const method on a temporary object. I find it quite useful.

OK. I forgot that `shared_ptr` constructor accepts `unique_ptr`. However why  forbid for example quick reading of a first line of file?

```
std::array<char, 140> line;
std::istream{"MyFile.txt"}.readline(line, line.size()-1);
```

Maybe more interesting is why binding non-const lvalue reference to temporary is forbidden? Non-const reference to lvalue parameter means output parameter. Allowing binding to temporary would lead to subtle bugs due to conversions. For example

```
void readShort(short & out)
{
   out = 7;
}

long var;
readShort(var);
```

There is a temporary `short` created to match function parameter type. Now binding it to reference is forbidden. If you allow it, function would assign to temporary and then the result would be thrown away.

**Update**

> Could you also explain why binding temporary object to local non-const lvalue reference is not allowed?

Now there is one set of rules for binding references to objects, no matter if it is done during function call or local reference definition. Creating two different sets of rules depending on context would complicate (already very complicated) language and requires some justification. I guess no one yet came with request for such change that would convince standard committee.

Comment: This does show the sort of general situation where it might be useful, but note that `std::shared_ptr<MyClass> mySharedObject{createObject()};` would actually do the same thing, via the `shared_ptr` constructor taking an rvalue `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @aschepler OK, I added some other example. Creating a real world case might be too long.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Thanks! Could you also explain why binding temporary object to local non-const lvalue reference is not allowed? Like `myclass& ref = myclass{}`? Why the cpp designer does not allow this to prolong the object's lifetime just as const lvalue reference does? I really appreciate it if you can point out the reason for this prohibition.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Thanks! I think I may find a reason why binding temporary to local non-const reference is not allowed without the reason of consistency. Could you check my answer to see if that make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just some add-up : reason why binding temporary to local non-const lvalue reference is not allowed.

First, please read my accepted answer.

Then, if binding temporary to local non-const lvalue reference is allowed, you may write the code like this :

```
void foo(double& x);
int& ref = 1;
foo(ref);
```

And that's problematic for the same reason that my accepted answer provided.